# vmware fusion: DHCP issues different IP per reboot

Tags: vmware

I'm using VMWare Fusion 10 on MacOS. I've got 2 vms that are running CentOS 7 behind a NAT network - 10.0.1.0/24. I've noticed that on each reboot, the VM receives a different IP address from the internal DHCP server.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: By either not using DHCP or configuring your DHCP server to reserve IPs for those machines.

Comment: this is internal DHCP server in vmware

Comment: The same principals still apply. [Modifying the DHCP settings of vmnet1 and vmnet8 in Fusion (1026510)](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1026510)